# Generics in typescript - not assignable to type / parameter of type

Tags: javascript, typescript, templates, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am having the following two service calls, which both are using the method concertDates().

```
private callMyFirstService(params: MyParams): Observable<MyDto> {
    return this.http.post<MyDto>(params).pipe(map(response => this.convertDates<MyDto>(response)));
}

private callMySecondService(params: MyOtherParams): Observable<MyAnotherDto> {
    return this.http.post<MyAnotherDto>(params).pipe(map(response => this.convertDates<MyAnotherDto>(response)));
}
```

Since these methods are operating with another type of dtos, I try to implement some generic funtion which can be called in both cases.
I have something like that:

```
private convertDates<type>(input: type): type {
    for (const key in input) {
        if (!input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (typeof input[key] === 'object') {
            this.convertDates(input[key]);
        } else if (typeof input[key] === 'string' && this.MY_REGEXP.test(input[key])) {
            input[key] = new Date(input[key]);
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

This does not seem to work, becase I always get:

```
Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'type[Extract<keyof type, string>]'
```

and...

```
Argument of type 'type[Extract<keyof type, string>]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'type[string]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Whatever type that `type` is has a specific shape. You seem to be expecting an object that has some properties that are strings, which you are *changing* to be a `Date` instead. This means that you are in violation of that type.

Or more simply:

```
const obj = { maybeDate: 'foo' } // type is { maybeDate: string }
obj.maybeDate = new Date() // error
```

The type of `maybeDate` is `string`, so you can't just assign a `Date` to that slot. That violates the type.

---

Typically when doing a conversion like that, you need to cast the object to an intermediary type, and then cast it to the final type.

```
const obj = { maybeDate: 'foo' } // type is { maybeDate: string }
const objIntermediate = obj as { maybeDate: string | Date }
objIntermediate.maybeDate = new Date()
const objFinal = objIntermediate as { maybeDate: Date }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvGBbAhgT3gFMARHKQgLhgHIAzEEamAXxgHo2Yo8AHQmAJYQM2fEVLkq0AE4CwAcxYAoUJFgJEASTDlpWQgBMBZfmg0wcwzLgIkTUqLIUwAPjAn9mSjdt36jJgB0NuImqDBghADu7iYAFACUKuDQcEgAYnI4ADbhPjqEeobG5BZWorYeVB4sQA)

---

At this point it's important to say that your logic is impossible to type. First, because typescript doesn't support regex transformations, but more importantly the type system can't know if a `string` should be converted into a date, since it won't know the contents of that string ahead of time.

```
interface MyDto {
  name: string
  createdAt: string // How could typescript possible know this is a date string?
}
```

---

I've solved in my own codebase in a different way. I type the `Dto` to have the fields as `Date`, for example:

```
interface MyDto {
  name: string
  createdAt: Date
}
```

And then use some custom JSON decoder logic to change the fields:

```
/** Parse JSON content from a response. If any string matches the ISO date time format, convert it to a Date. */
async function decodeJson(res: Response): Promise<any> {
  return JSON.parse(await res.text(), (key: string, value: unknown) => {
    if (typeof value === 'string' && dateFormat.test(value)) {
      return new Date(value)
    }
    return value
  })
}
const dateFormat = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}Z$/
```

Which is called by:

```
function fetchStuff<T>(path: string) {
  const res = await window.fetch(path)
  const json = await decodeJson(res)
  return json as T
}

// Then in some async function
const myStuff = await fetchStuff<MyDto>('/api/foo')
myStuff.createdAt.getHours() // works
```

This works because the response is `any` until it's cast to the generic type, so typescript let's you do anything with it. (I'm not sure how to adapt this to rxjs powered code, to be honest)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=40&pln=24&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8AiYD2yDeAUMsiHALYQBcyAzmFKAObHIJQRyQAmAgmDUxcIhAL6FCAegBU05AAU4UWigBSAZQDyAOTY5wEcMhhQc5ZHGQdaAB30qAdMgCSMCyHR0GzZOS4IACwhaZDAgly1kbmFQ4EpjHCg-MAAaPRAAN2gwZGAc3AtkIUgnaUlCOFp0EARjAFcasGB9KIgEHG4IVVp9AAprGgAlYLsQFQBKGnlTcmAVAB44DwA+AlYOMDqoEGQNHQcbJRVeuAB3ODyrYIdIAA8wXvG03oBrCHQaekYQJjSMuAANnVqMgGi8QDhTiBxsgALyrIgkEjANy9MDoGwQHBuf5AlCwgnIADkX2YROQADIKVFhAAxRLJG7BB644HjGGIpEkDZbHYgCCnIrCXqsiDjVgkcRcnnbZCi1iicXidpjHLRSD0pJcOHISQAPQAOtx8AAWUQAWiN+AATBarbaACr20RUZ2u422hxWgDMogAWgAScoVKo1eqNZo7GAQMCBdSbGAweYO5a9Q5hT7eH4c1gq+hXEKwiznS6nUDcSEOaOxgJprgBcUkPM5ABWPR2RbOFzVbQ6XXb-WCjaum1lbZalWQDrEEkq1VqMAaCCaLSYOEeayb9hy5HQ8bqiZ1Xcu1bjCaTGGwOFTRMkcBswEkMBwOCJw93+8TDnYnB4-AcTAxgAEjgWy0BukiSMgpyJC8tAzkAA)

The biggest downside of this whole approach of auto-converting dates is that if someone manually types into some text field a date like string, it will get converted into a Date, but your Dto will have that typed as a string, and that could crash your application. For example someone types in their name as `2015-01-02`. In my application, this is so exceedingly unlikely that it's worth the convenience. But that may not be tolerable for you.

---

As a final side note, the headaches that would have been saved if JSON had a native `Date` type are no doubt innumerable...